# incorrect binary tree

Tags: c, binary-tree, huffman-code

```
while(count != 25) {
    tail = head;
    new_node = (binary_node*)malloc(sizeof(binary_node));
    while(tail->next != NULL)
        tail = tail->next;
    tail->next = new_node;  
    new_node->element.frequency = (p->element.frequency + q->element.frequency);
    new_node->LSON = p;
    new_node->LSON->RTAG = 0;
    new_node->RSON = q;
    new_node->RSON->RTAG = 1;   
    head = new_node;
    n = n - 1;
    head = q->next;
    sort(n, head);


    p = head;
    q = p->next;
    count++;
}
```

The code above should generate a huffman tree. However, the binary tree that is formed is incorrect. All the nodes that contains a letter should be a leaf or a node without a son but some alphabet nodes still have sons. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: nope. i am only trying to create a huffman tree right now because i can't do it in class.

Comment: I don't see a single variable declaration, nor any comments.  While I can guess at some of the types and meanings, debugging by ESP is no fun.   Please show more complete code, and please add meaningful comments.

Comment: And an example data-set would be useful as well.

Comment: Also, what did you learn by stepping through your code in a debugger?

Comment: You never set `new_node->next` to `NULL`.

Comment: that is just a code snippet. that is where the part that i think, after all the debugging, results to an error. all variables are properly declared. p q and head are node pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` returns you a memory area full of garbage.

Since you never set for the new_node that it's not an alphabet node sometimes you'll find garabage there saying that it is actually an alphabet node.

consequence for verification: you should find more alphabet nodes that you originally had.

Comment: i tried setting a character for new_node so that it does not become an alphabet node. but its still the same. there is still a node that appears to be an alphabet node but has a right and left son